# Why jQuery function is not working after ctlr+f5?

Tags: javascript, jquery

That's real'y interesting issue that I've seen before. I have more than one function on my .js file and all work very well so if I refresh my page with <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> there is no any problem it works again, but if I refresh my page with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> then my jQuery function is not working. Only I write another plugin is working as expected. So I want to ask you, has anyone else encountered the same problem?

And my example code.

```
$(function(){
//my code here
})
```

and these functions are not in document.ready or window.load so I have another function which I called with name as below

```
function equalHeight(){
//my code here..
}
equalHeight(); 
function getListHeight(){
//my code here..
}
getListHeight();
```

these codes are not in `document.ready` or `window.load`

Comment: Why you not use with `document.ready` or `window.load` .add your code inside the `document.ready` or `window.load`

Comment: if I put my functions inside `document.ready` or `window.load` will they work correctly ?

Comment: Actual proper code would be nice, maybe a [mcve]. It's very hard to say with "here's code I don't show" and "is not working"

Comment: @ani_css ..refer From above statement & code. its working you are add code with inside `document.ready` or `window.load` ..like => `$(document).ready(function(){ equalHeight(); getListHeight();})`

Comment: so is my code true ?
`function equalHeight(){
}
$(document).ready(function(){
equalHeight();
});`